# How to add item to Local SQL Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Currently I am trying to create a calendar and trying to work with tables through a local SQL database. While I was shown how to select and create new databases and tables, I can't get anything inserted. I've searched around and most of what I've seen uses SqlConnection, however, if I try to use that it doesn't recognize the namespace, and trying to use the using-- command haven't resulted in much. 

 
Right now this is my code, including the form where the user enters data to where I try to push it into the database:

```
<h3>Set a reminder/event</h3>


        <% string setReminderValue = Request.QueryString["setReminder"]; %>
        <!-- Takes the ID of the date that the user selects above (setReminder), converts it and allows the form to use it further as the name of eventId. -->

        <form method="POST" action="WebForm1.aspx"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="eventId" value="<%= setReminderValue %>" />
            Event name: <input type="text" name="reminderName" /> <br />
            <input type="submit" name="submitReminder" value="Set"> <br /> 

        </form>            


    <% 

        }

        var submitReminder = Request["submitReminder"];
        var reminderName = Request["reminderName"];
        var eventId = Request["eventId"];



        if (submitReminder != null)
        { 

            var cmd = "INSERT INTO CalendarData(Day, Text) VALUES('eventId' , 'reminderName')";
// Currently with no functionality, but how to execute it is outside my knowledge range, which isn't very large at all, yet.

        }
         %>
```

Comment: uhm what you posted has no functionality at all in regards to inserting.  you set a varialbe cmd to a string that contains an insert command but you don't use it at all. is that the whole code? if so then that is the reason why it does nothing

Comment: @Thomas It is indeed the whole code, but to my defense I can say I am *very* new at C#, thus I'm not entirely sure how to actually execute things as such.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials online. Have you tried google?

Comment: @FelixPamittan Like I said in the original post, I have googled around a good bunch, all I can find is people using SqlConnection and if thats a thing i *need* to use, I'm also getting errors from that.

Comment: if you want answers in regards to that then put the example of when you use sql connection and get errors in there and also put in what the error is (many overlook the last part and get comments to put it in then). That aside there is either a sql connection or entityframework  which are the most prominent variants as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Thomas Well If I, in the most "beginner-friendly" way coudl get the INSERT command executed that would be nice to start with. All I am doing is using "using System.Data.SqlClient;" in my .cs file, as well as try to use SqlCommands. Once I've done that, it doesn't recognize the namespace/reference.

Comment: Youtube has a bunch of great videos, maybe start there... A video such as  
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3FpM8f2suI will give you everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try to exectue your command like this:

```
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost; Database=YOURDATABASENAME;UserId=YOURLOGINNAME;Password=YOURPASSWORD;");
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("YOUR CMD STRING");
        int affectedRows = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

For using an sql client you would need to use:  System.Data.SqlClient. A different option is to right click on the SqlConnection and use the change and using there that inserts the using (sry got not an english version of the studio so not sure what the exact names in english are).  That aside the usage is as is:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql =  "INSERT INTO CalendarData(Day, Text) VALUES(@param1,@param2)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,connection);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = eventId;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2", SqlDbType.Varchar, 50).value = reminderName;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    connection.Close();
}
```

So what does this do? The using makes sure that the variable is disposed of afterwards and should also close the connection (although I personally tend to write connection.Close() regardless as I had a few strange cases in the past).

Then you set the command text and execute the non query  (nonquery as you dont want a result but make an insert).

The @param are place holders which you then define what they are really standing for by saying cmd.Parameters.Add.  This helps to avoid sql injections as the parameters adding converts the values appropriately so that sql injection is not a problem.

myconnectionString you need to put in how the program has to connect to your server (you will have to look up appropriate strings for how you need to connect as they contain all infos necessary for the connect and are thus system specific)

Comment: Thats the issue though, even although I am having the correct using command in the .cs file, and have the reference loaded, its complaining and telling me I don't. Also to you if you see this, @StepUp

Comment: That is unusal if you have the correct using statemejnt in your source file he souldn't complain (at least if he doesnt complain about the using itself then that menas he knows the reference).  what version of visual studio are you using

Comment: I'm using VS2013, and if i manually add the System.Data.SqlClient or whatever it was in front of the command, it does recognize it as a reference while I do still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your last sql statements are not provided.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO dbo.CalendarData(Day, Text) VALUES (@eventId, @reminderName)";
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    //a shorter syntax to adding parameters
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eventId", 1);

    command.Parameters.Add("@reminderName", "abc");

    //make sure you open and close(after executing) the connection
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    connection.Close();
}
```